# Settings -> Reading -> Posts Page ->Blog -- is not working in my website

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I have a problem with blog posts on my website.
The Blog doesn't show posts. I tried several times to set the 'blog page' as a 'posts page' but the setting doesn't show any effect/change.
Settings -> Reading -> Posts Page ->Blog

I can understand that the real problem is in the WordPress "Reading Setting".
I have installed a paid theme that does not show blog posts. I contacted Theme Support as well but they did not respond. I also tried to use a plugin but it is also a mess.

I updated the theme and plugins.
I'm a bit stuck on this one, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could be that that theme doesn't have a template for displaying posts. Try waiting for the support to answer. If they don't, request a refund and find another theme. Because this is a paid theme we will have no way to help you without owning that theme ourselves and replicating this issue.

Comment: If @Buttered_Toast is right, then I recommend you switch themes. If they failed to provide a fallback for displaying posts, I can't imagine what else was left out.